# How to set thumbnail size using wp query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_query` method to display all my woocommerce products, but I have applied Google's PageSpeed tool and found out that the images size are too large, and taking me longer to load.

I'm aware WordPress has duplication of images with different size that has been uploaded, but I don't know how to approach the size I want.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'product_cat'    => $cat,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if (have_posts()):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> 
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>"/>
                <?php
                if(!$product->managing_stock() && !$product->is_in_stock()) {
                    echo '<div class="out">OUT OF STOCK</div>';
                }
                if($product->is_on_sale()){
                    echo '<div class="sale">SALE</div>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <span class="title">
                <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            </span>
            <span class="price">
                <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
  endif;
```

I want the images to be size 900x300.

How can I set images size using `WP_Query` arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to approach different sizes:

You need to insert the size's name (thumbnail, full, etc.) as a parameter inside the the_post_thumbnail_url() function. For example:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>
```

Note that [the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) echoes the url already, no need to echo it again. If you don't want the function to directly echo it, use [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) instead. (Notice that the two functions require different sets and orders of parameters.)

## How to set up a size:

The default sizes are thumbnail, medium, large, and full.

None of them have a dimension of 900 x 300.

You can either go to Settings->Media in your WP dashboard and change one of the settings, or you can add the following in your ***functions.php***:

```
add_image_size('NEW_NAME', 900, 300);
```

Read about the parameters of [add_image_size()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) function if you need any customization.

Comment: You can use the 'large' size  and manipulate the image with CSS. However, if you think that image must be of appropriate size, then add the size. Remember, WordPress will save an additional copy of every single image that is uploaded, for every single add_image_size() function that you use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there other size parameters other than `('thumbnail');`?

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider accepting it as correct answer @Yotam